# Error in model.frame.default(formula = mpg01 ~ ., data = list(cylinders = c(8, : variable lengths differ (found for 'cylinders')

Tags: r, svm

I am not sure how to fix the length error in my code. Everything runs smoothly until I run svm.tune. Please advise!

```
library(ISLR)
attach(Auto)
n <- nrow(Auto)
mpg01 <- rep(0, length(mpg))
mpg01[mpg > median(mpg)] <- 1
mpg01 <- as.factor(mpg01)
Auto <- data.frame(Auto, mpg01)
Auto$mpg = NULL

set.seed(1)
train <- sample(1:n, 0.8*n)
x.train <- Auto[train,-9]
x.test <- Auto[-train,-9]
y.train <- Auto$mpg01[train]
y.test <- Auto$mpg01[-train]

library(e1071)
RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
set.seed(1)
svm.tune <- tune(method=svm, 
                 mpg01~., data = x.train,
                 kernel = "linear",
                 ranges = list(cost = c(0.01,0.1,1,5,10)))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is customary for the `data` to contain the response variable as well, so instead of splitting the train and test into x and y, you keep the train all in one data frame and the test in one data frame.

```
xy.train <- Auto[train,]
xy.test <- Auto[-train,]

library(e1071)
#RNGkind(sample.kind = "Rounding")
set.seed(1)
svm.tune <- tune(method=svm, 
                 mpg01~., data = xy.train,
                 kernel = "linear",
                 ranges = list(cost = c(0.01,0.1,1,5,10)))
```